# In the Midori browser, the font is confusing

Tags: fonts, browser

please see pic below.

[image]

ubuntu 16.04

all fontconfig files in home had been deleted. unity-tweak-tool also no effect.

Comment: confusing? how? what you expected? and also why are you considering those errors?

Comment: confusing means those font is not what I selected. You can see I selected Courier font, but display font is error one.

Comment: What error? The text is rendered with the correct font

Comment: Can you give the link of that page?

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html